# Maintaining a complicated installer supporting per-user and everyone

Tags: user-interface, rubberduck, installer, pascal-script

Another challenge for developing [rubberduck VBA project](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) is to develop an installer that support per-user mode and everyone-mode.

Normally with an MSI package, one has a bootstrapper so it is possible to defer the privilege escalation until it is determined that it is in fact necessary. However Inno Setup doesn't work like that; it's not a MSI package + bootstrapper but literally an application. Therefore, I adapted the code sample from this [SO thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556853/make-inno-setup-installer-request-privileges-elevation-only-when-needed) and [SO thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34330668/inno-setup-custom-dialog-with-per-user-or-per-machine-installation).

With some changes, I came up with this setup procedure to create 2 custom pages to support both modes and addin registration. The beauty is that when running in elevated context, the addin page is *never* shown; it is only available when running unelevated. (For whatever reasons, writing registry entries to HKCU in elevated context caused problems).

```
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  HasElevateSwitch := CmdLineParamExists('/ELEVATE');
  Log(Format('HasElevateSwitch: %d', [HasElevateSwitch]));
  Log(Format('IsElevated: %d', [IsElevated()]));

  //Assume we are installing for all users if we were elevated
  ShouldInstallAllUsers := HasElevateSwitch;

  InstallForWhoOptionPage :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(
      wpWelcome,
      ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersCaption}'), 
      ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersMessage}'),
      ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersAdminDescription}'),
      True, False);
  InstallForWhoOptionPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersAdminButtonCaption}'));
  InstallForWhoOptionPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersUserButtonCaption}'));

  if PerUserOnly then
  begin
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.Values[1] := true;
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.CheckListBox.ItemEnabled[0] := false;
  end
    else if IsElevated() then
  begin
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.Values[0] := true;
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.CheckListBox.ItemEnabled[1] := false;
  end
    else
  begin
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.Values[1] := true;
  end;

  RegisterAddInOptionPage :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(
      wpInstalling,
      ExpandConstant('{cm:RegisterAddInCaption}'),
      ExpandConstant('{cm:RegisterAddInMessage}'),
      ExpandConstant('{cm:RegisterAddInDescription}'),
      False, False);

  RegisterAddInOptionPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:RegisterAddInButtonCaption}'));
  RegisterAddInOptionPage.CheckListBox.ItemEnabled[0] := not IsElevated();
  RegisterAddInOptionPage.Values[0] := not IsElevated();
end;
```

However, I found it was not enough. The other challenge I have is that I have to register the Rubberduck AddIn using `HKCU` hive; there is *no* mechanism for all users registration. Therefore, we're basically mixing potential `HKLM` entries and `HKCU` entries for a "everyone" install.

I also observed that when mixing modes, uninstalling or installing over a previous version became problematic and could throw errors. Thus, I had to incorporate the suggestion from [SO thread 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000296/inno-setup-how-to-automatically-uninstall-previous-installed-version) to support automatic uninstall of previous versions.

Relevant code:

```
function GetUninstallString(AppId: string): String;
var
  sAppId: string;
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  if AppId = '' then
    sAppId := GetAppId('')
  else
    sAppId := AppId;

  sUnInstPath := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + sAppId + '_is1';
  Log('Looking in registry: ' + sUnInstPath);
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Log('Result of registry query: ' + sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;

...

function UnInstallOldVersion(AppId: string): integer;
var
  sUnInstallString: string;
  iResultCode: integer;
begin
  // default return value
  Result := 0;

  // get the uninstall string of the old app
  sUnInstallString := GetUninstallString(AppId);
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if Exec(sUnInstallString, '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode) then
      Result := 3
    else
      Result := 2;
  end else
    Result := 1;
end;
```

But that was not enough! After analyzing a bit more, I settled on differentiating the `AppId` for each mode. That enables both everyone and per-user mode to be installed on the same computer, which might be over-engineering it a bit but this seems to give the best experience and most important, empowers the users to install their favorite ducky without having to do the UAC tap dance if they can't.

The relevant code:

```
EveryoneAppMode = 'Everyone';
EveryoneAppId = '{979AFF96-DD9E-4FC2-802D-9E0C36A60D09}';
PerUserAppMode = 'PerUser';
PerUserAppId = '{DF0E0E6F-2CED-482E-831C-7E9721EB66AA}';

...

function GetAppId(AppMode: string): string;
begin
  if AppMode = EveryoneAppMode then
    result := EveryoneAppId
  else if AppMode = PerUserAppMode then
    result := PerUserAppId
  else
    if ShouldInstallAllUsers then
      result := EveryoneAppId
    else
      result := PerUserAppId
end;
```

But here's the biggest concern: the script went from 236 lines to more than 1000 lines (gasp!), and it's in *Pascal* (gasp!) and we're basically a bunch of C# programmers. Talk about a duck out of water! (wait that doesn't work...)

Now, the count of lines is somewhat artificially pumped up because I included lot of comments because again, I'm out of comfort zone and if I am, it's likely other contributors will be and it's in my best interest to make it understandable, even if we end up being more noisy and chatty.

**So, how can we make it more approachable, especially to those who might not be fluent in Pascal?**

The complete Inno Setup Installer script [(also available here)](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/pull/3836/files#diff-18e7b962921ff7a0699f1155994825d4):

```
#pragma include __INCLUDE__ + ";" + SourcePath + "\Includes\"

#define protected
#ifndef Config
#define Config "Debug"
#endif
#define BuildDir ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(SourcePath)) + "\bin\" + Config + "\"
#define IncludesDir SourcePath + "\Includes\"
#define AppName "Rubberduck"
#define AddinDLL "Rubberduck.dll"
#define Tlb32bit "Rubberduck.x32.tlb"
#define Tlb64bit "Rubberduck.x64.tlb"
#define DllFullPath BuildDir + AddinDLL
#define Tlb32bitFullPath BuildDir + Tlb32bit
#define Tlb64bitFullPath BuildDir + Tlb64bit 
#define AppVersion GetFileVersion(BuildDir + "Rubberduck.dll")
#define AppPublisher "Rubberduck"
#define AppURL "http://rubberduckvba.com"
#define License SourcePath + "\Includes\License.rtf"
#define OutputDirectory SourcePath + "Installers\"
#define AddinProgId "Rubberduck.Extension"
#define AddinCLSID "8D052AD8-BBD2-4C59-8DEC-F697CA1F8A66"

; Output the defined constants to aid in verification
#pragma message "Include: " + __INCLUDE__
#pragma message "Config: " + Config
#pragma message "SourcePath: " + SourcePath
#pragma message "BuildDir: " + BuildDir
#pragma message "AppName: " + AppName
#pragma message "AddinDLL: " + AddinDLL
#pragma message "DllFullPath: " + DllFullPath
#pragma message "Tlb32bitFullPath: " + Tlb32bitFullPath
#pragma message "Tlb64bitFullPath: " + Tlb64bitFullPath
#pragma message "AppVersion: " + AppVersion
#pragma message "AppPublisher: " + AppPublisher
#pragma message "AppURL: " + AppURL
#pragma message "License: " + License
#pragma message "OutputDirectory: " + OutputDirectory 
#pragma message "AddinProgId: " + AddinProgId
#pragma message "AddinCLSID: " + AddInCLSID

[Setup]
; The Previous language must be no when AppId uses constants
UsePreviousLanguage=no
AppId={code:GetAppId}
AppName={#AppName}
AppVersion={#AppVersion}
AppPublisher={#AppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#AppURL}
AppSupportURL={#AppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#AppURL}
DefaultDirName={code:GetDefaultDirName}
DefaultGroupName=Rubberduck
AllowNoIcons=yes
LicenseFile={#License}
OutputDir={#OutputDirectory}
OutputBaseFilename=Rubberduck.Setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

ArchitecturesAllowed=x86 x64
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64

SetupLogging=yes
PrivilegesRequired=lowest

UninstallFilesDir={app}\Installers
UninstallDisplayName={code:GetUninstallDisplayName}
UninstallDisplayIcon=ducky.ico
Uninstallable=ShouldCreateUninstaller()
CreateUninstallRegKey=ShouldCreateUninstaller()

; should be 55 x 58 bitmap; use the included non-default bitamp from IS
WizardSmallImageFile=compiler:WizModernSmallImage-IS.bmp

; should be a 164 x 314 bitmap
WizardImageFile=InstallerBitMap.bmp

[Languages]
Name: "English"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"
Name: "French"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\French.isl"
Name: "German"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"

[Files]
; Install the correct bitness binaries.
Source: "{#BuildDir}*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs replacesameversion; Excludes: "Rubberduck.Deployment.*,Rubberduck.dll.xml,Rubberduck.x32.tlb.xml,{#AddinDLL},\NativeBinaries"; Check: CheckShouldInstallFiles
Source: "{#BuildDir}{#AddinDLL}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion; Check: CheckShouldInstallFiles;

; Included only if installed for all users to enable self-registration for other users on machine
Source: "{#IncludesDir}Rubberduck.RegisterAddIn.bat"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion; Check: InstallAllUsers;
Source: "{#IncludesDir}Rubberduck.RegisterAddIn.reg"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion replacesameversion; Check: InstallAllUsers;

[Registry]
; DO NOT attempt to register VBE Add-In with this section. It doesn't work
; Use [Code] section (RegisterAddIn procedure) to register the entries instead.
#include <Rubberduck.reg.iss>

[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: "{userappdata}\{#AppName}"

[CustomMessages]
; TODO add additional languages here by adding include files in \Includes folder
;      and uncomment or add lines to include the file.
#include <English.CustomMessages.iss>
; #include <French.CustomMessages.iss>
; #include <German.CustomMessages.iss>

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:ProgramOnTheWeb,{#AppName}}"; Filename: "{#AppURL}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#AppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"

; Included only if installed for all users to enable self-registration for other users on machine
Name: "{group}\{cm:RegisterAddin, {#AppName}}"; Filename: "{app}\Rubberduck.RegisterAddIn.bat"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Check: InstallAllUsers;

[Code]
///<remarks>
/// The code section is divided into subsections:
///   global declarations of const and variables
///   external functions
///   helper functions
///   event functions
///</remarks>

// Global declarations Section

type
  HINSTANCE = THandle;

const
   ///<remarks>
   ///Identifiers for installation in everyone mode to support
   ///functions that needs to distinguish between install modes.
   ///</remarks>
   EveryoneAppMode = 'Everyone';
   EveryoneAppId = '{979AFF96-DD9E-4FC2-802D-9E0C36A60D09}';
   PerUserAppMode = 'PerUser';
   PerUserAppId = '{DF0E0E6F-2CED-482E-831C-7E9721EB66AA}';

  ///<remarks>
  ///Pseudo-Bitwise enum to support functions for
  ///checking previous versions of different modes.
  ///Pascal scripting doesn't have bitwise operators 
  ///so we improvise....
  ///<remarks>
  NoneIsInstalled = 0; 
  PerUserIsInstalled = 1;
  EveryoneIsInstalled = 2; 
  BothAreInstalled = 3;

var
  ///<remarks>
  ///Flag to indicate that we automatically skipped pages during an 
  ///elevated install.
  ///
  ///The flag should be only changed within the <see cref="ShouldSkipPage" /> 
  ///event function. Treat it as read-only in all other contexts.
  ///</remarks>
  PagesSkipped: Boolean;

  ///<remarks>
  ///Custom page to select whether the installer should run for the
  ///current user only or for all users (requiring elevation). 
  ///Configured in the WizardInitialize event function.
  ///</remarks>
  InstallForWhoOptionPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

  ///<remarks>
  ///Custom page to indicate whether the installer should create per-user
  ///registry key to make VBE addin available to the application. 
  ///<see cref="RegisterAddIn" />
  ///</remakrs>
  RegisterAddInOptionPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;

  ///<remarks>
  ///Set by the <see cref="RegisterAddInOptionPage" />; should be
  ///read-only normally. When set to true, it is used to check if
  ///elevation is needed for the installer.
  ///</remarks>
  ShouldInstallAllUsers: Boolean;

  ///<remarks>
  ///When the non-elevated installer launches the elevated installer
  ///via the <see cref="Elevate" />, it will pass in a switch. This 
  ///helps us to know that the elevated installer was started in this 
  ///manner rather than user right-clicking and choosing "Run As Administrator".
  ///This mainly influences whether we should skip the pages. Treat it 
  ///as read-only in all contexts other than <see cref="InitializeWizard" />.
  ///<remarks>
  HasElevateSwitch : Boolean;

  ///<remarks>
  ///Indicates that the installer can only run in per-user only. This is typically
  ///when there is a previous version of Rubberduck and the user either won't or
  ///can't uninstall it. Therefore, we cannot safely install using all-user mode
  ///in this context. This is set in the <see cref="SetupInitialize" /> event 
  ///function and should be read-only in all other contexts.
  ///</remarks>
  PerUserOnly : Boolean;

// External functions section

///<remarks>
///Used to select correct subtype of Win32 API
///based on the installer's encoding. 
///<remarks>
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

///<remarks>
///Win32 API function used to launch a 2nd instance of the installer
///under elevated context, used by <see cref="Elevate" />.
///</remarks>
function ShellExecute(hwnd: HWND; lpOperation: string; lpFile: string;
  lpParameters: string; lpDirectory: string; nShowCmd: Integer): HINSTANCE;
  external 'ShellExecute{#AW}@shell32.dll stdcall';

// Helper functions section

///<remarks>
///Encapuslate the check whether the installer is running in an
///elevated context or not. This does not indicate whether the
///installer was launched by a non-elevated installer, however.
///<see cref="HasElevateSwitch" />
///</remarks>
function IsElevated: Boolean;
begin
  Result := IsAdminLoggedOn or IsPowerUserLoggedOn;
end;

///<remarks>
///Generic helper function to parse the command line arguments,
///and indicate whether a particular argument was passed in.
///</remarks>
function CmdLineParamExists(const Value: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;  
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
    if CompareText(ParamStr(I), Value) = 0 then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
end;

///<remarks>
///Used to determine whether a install directory that user 
///selected is in fact writable by the user, especially 
///for non-elevated installation. 
///</remarks>
function HaveWriteAccessToApp: Boolean;
var
  FileName: string;
begin
  FileName := AddBackslash(WizardDirValue) + 'writetest.tmp';
  Result := SaveStringToFile(FileName, 'test', False);
  if Result then
  begin
    Log(Format(
      'Have write aElevationRequiredForSelectedFolderWarningccess to the last installation path [%s]', [WizardDirValue]));
    DeleteFile(FileName);
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Does not have write access to the last installation path [%s]', [
      WizardDirValue]));
  end;
end;

///<remarks>
///When user requests install for all users or into a protected directory,
///and the current installer isn't elevated, it will create a second instance
///of itself, passing in all the switches, and adding the `/ELEVATE` switch
///to complete the installation of the add-in under the elevated context.
///The original installer does not terminate but rather remains open for the
///elevated install to complete so that the user can then proceed with VBE
///addin registration on the <see cref="RegisterAddInOptionPage" /> page.
///<remarks>
function Elevate: Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  instance: HINSTANCE;
  Params: string;
  S: string;
begin
  { Collect current instance parameters }
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
  begin
    S := ParamStr(I);
    Log('Parameter: ' + S);
    { Unique log file name for the elevated instance }
    if CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 5), '/LOG=') = 0 then
    begin
      S := S + 'elevated';
    end;
    { Do not pass our /SL5 switch }
    if CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 5), '/SL5=') <> 0 then
    begin
      Params := Params + AddQuotes(S) + ' ';
    end;
  end;

  if Pos('/DIR', Params) = 0 then
    Params := Params + ExpandConstant('/DIR="{app}" ');
  { ... and add selected language }
  if Pos('/LANG', Params) = 0 then
    Params := Params + '/LANG=' + ActiveLanguage + ' ';
  if Pos('/ELEVATE', Params) = 0 then
    Params := Params + '/ELEVATE';

  Log(Format('Elevating setup with parameters [%s]', [Params]));
  instance := ShellExecute(0, 'runas', ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), Params, '', SW_SHOW);
  Log(Format('Running elevated setup returned [%d]', [instance]));
  Result := (instance > 32);
  { if elevated executing of this setup succeeded, then... }
  if Result then
  begin
    Log('Elevation succeeded');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log(Format('Elevation failed [%s]', [SysErrorMessage(instance)]));
  end;
end;

///<remarks>
///Adapted from http://kynosarges.org/DotNetVersion.html; used during
///the <see cref="InitializeSetup"> event function to ensure that the
///.NET framework is present on the computer.
///</remarks>
function IsDotNetDetected(version: string; service: cardinal): boolean;
// Indicates whether the specified version and service pack of the .NET Framework is installed.
//
// version -- Specify one of these strings for the required .NET Framework version:
//    'v1.1.4322'     .NET Framework 1.1
//    'v2.0.50727'    .NET Framework 2.0
//    'v3.0'          .NET Framework 3.0
//    'v3.5'          .NET Framework 3.5
//    'v4\Client'     .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile
//    'v4\Full'       .NET Framework 4.0 Full Installation
//    'v4.5'          .NET Framework 4.5
//
// service -- Specify any non-negative integer for the required service pack level:
//    0               No service packs required
//    1, 2, etc.      Service pack 1, 2, etc. required
var
    key: string;
    install, release, serviceCount: cardinal;
    check45, success: boolean;
begin
    // .NET 4.5 installs as update to .NET 4.0 Full
    if version = 'v4.5' then begin
        version := 'v4\Full';
        check45 := true;
    end else
        check45 := false;

    // installation key group for all .NET versions
    key := 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\' + version;

    // .NET 3.0 uses value InstallSuccess in subkey Setup
    if Pos('v3.0', version) = 1 then begin
        success := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key + '\Setup', 'InstallSuccess', install);
    end else begin
        success := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'Install', install);
    end;

    // .NET 4.0/4.5 uses value Servicing instead of SP
    if Pos('v4', version) = 1 then begin
        success := success and RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'Servicing', serviceCount);
    end else begin
        success := success and RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'SP', serviceCount);
    end;

    // .NET 4.5 uses additional value Release
    if check45 then begin
        success := success and RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'Release', release);
        success := success and (release >= 378389);
    end;

    result := success and (install = 1) and (serviceCount >= service);
end;

///<remarks>
///Helper function used in non-code sections to set the default directory
///to be installed, based on the elevation context.
///</remarks>
function GetDefaultDirName(Param: string): string;
begin
  if IsElevated() then
  begin
    Result := ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}{\}{#AppName}');
  end
    else
  begin
    Result := ExpandConstant('{localappdata}{\}{#AppName}')
  end;
end;

///<remarks>
///Helper function used in non-code sections to provide the path that was
///either set by installer by default or customized by the user.
///</remarks>
function GetInstallPath(Unused: string): string;
begin
  result := ExpandConstant('{app}');
end;

///<remarks>
///Helper function used in non-code sections to provide the full path to
///the Rubberduck main DLL, based on the same path as <see cref="GetInstallPath" />
///</remarks>
function GetDllPath(Unused: string): string;
begin
  result := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\Rubberduck.dll';
end;

///<remarks>
///Helper function used in non-code sections to provide the full path to
///the 32-bit type library for Rubberduck main DLL, based on teh same path
///as <cref="GetInstallPath" />
///</remarks>
function GetTlbPath32(Unused: string): string;
begin
  result := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\Rubberduck.x32.tlb';
end;

///<remarks>
///Same as <see cref="GetTlbPath32" /> but for 64-bit.
///</remarks>
function GetTlbPath64(Unused: string): string;
begin
  result := ExpandConstant('{app}') + '\Rubberduck.x64.tlb';
end;

///<remarks>
///Helper function used in the Registry section to indicate whether
///the item should be installed. For example, HKLM registry requires
///elevated context, so the function must return true, while HKCU 
///counterpart will expect the opposite to be installed. This prevents
///comparable item being installed into both places.
///</remarks>
function InstallAllUsers():boolean;
begin
  result := ShouldInstallAllUsers and IsElevated();
end;

///<remarks>
///Helper function used in the File section to assess whether an
///file(s) should be installed based on whether there's privilege
///to do so. This guards against the case of both the non-elevated 
///installer and the elevated installer installing same files into
///same place, which will cause problems. This function ensures only
///one or other mode will actually install the files.
///</remarks>
function CheckShouldInstallFiles():boolean;
begin
  if ShouldInstallAllUsers then
    result := IsElevated()
  else
    result := true;
end;

///<remarks>
///Used by <see cref="RegisterAddIn" />, passing in parameters to actually create
///the per-user registry entries to enable VBE addin for that user.
///<remarks>
procedure RegisterAddinForIDE(const iRootKey: Integer; const sAddinSubKey: String; const sProgIDConnect: String);
begin
   RegWriteStringValue(iRootKey, sAddinSubKey + '\' + sProgIDConnect, 'FriendlyName', '{#AppName}');
   RegWriteStringValue(iRootKey, sAddinSubKey + '\' + sProgIDConnect, 'Description' , '{#AppName}');
   RegWriteDWordValue (iRootKey, sAddinSubKey + '\' + sProgIDConnect, 'LoadBehavior', 3);
end;

///<remarks>
///Unregisters the same keys, similar to <see cref="RegisterAddinForIDE" />
///</remarks>
procedure UnregisterAddinForIDE(const iRootKey: Integer; const sAddinSubKey: String; const sProgIDConnect: String);
begin
   if RegKeyExists(iRootKey, sAddinSubKey + '\' + sProgIDConnect) then
      RegDeleteKeyIncludingSubkeys(iRootKey, sAddinSubKey + '\' + sProgIDConnect);
end;

///<remarks>
///Called after successfully installing, including via the elevated installer
///to register the VBE addin. Should be never run under elevated context
///or the registration may not work as expected.
///</remarks>
procedure RegisterAddin();
begin
  if not IsElevated() then
  begin
    RegisterAddinForIDE(HKCU32, 'Software\Microsoft\VBA\VBE\6.0\Addins', '{#AddinProgId}');

    if IsWin64() then 
      RegisterAddinForIDE(HKCU64, 'Software\Microsoft\VBA\VBE\6.0\Addins64', '{#AddinProgId}');
  end;
end;

///<remarks>
///Delete registry keys created by <see cref="RegisterAddin" />
///</remarks>
procedure UnregisterAddin();
begin
  UnregisterAddinForIDE(HKCU32, 'Software\Microsoft\VBA\VBE\6.0\Addins', '{#AddinProgId}');
  if IsWin64() then 
    UnregisterAddinForIDE(HKCU64, 'Software\Microsoft\VBA\VBE\6.0\Addins64', '{#AddinProgId}');
end;

///<remarks>
///Generate AppId based on whether it's going to be 
///per-user or for all users. This enable separate
///install/uninstall of each mode. Used by AppId
///directive in the [Setup] section.
///</remarks>
///<param name="AppMode">
///If value is 'peruser', then returns per-user AppId
///If value is 'everyone', then returns everyone AppId
///Otherwise if left blank or contains invalid value, returns 
///the AppId based on ShouldInstallAllUsers 
///(e.g. based on user's selection.)
///</param>
function GetAppId(AppMode: string): string;
begin
  if AppMode = EveryoneAppMode then
    result := EveryoneAppId
  else if AppMode = PerUserAppMode then
    result := PerUserAppId
  else
    if ShouldInstallAllUsers then
      result := EveryoneAppId
    else
      result := PerUserAppId
end;

///<remarks>
///Used to help disambiguate multiple installs of Rubberduck 
///by providing a suffix to indicate which mode it is
///</remarks>
function GetAppSuffix(): string;
begin
  if ShouldInstallAllUsers then
    result := ExpandConstant('{cm:Everyone}')
  else
    result := ExpandConstant('{cm:PerUser}');
end;

///<remakrs>
///Provide a suffixed name of uninstaller to help identify what mode
///the version is installed in.
///</remarks>
function GetUninstallDisplayName(Unused: string): string;
begin
  result := ExpandConstant('{#AppName} (') + GetAppSuffix() + ') {#AppVersion}';
end;

///<remarks>
///Prevent creating an uninstaller from the non-elevated installer
///The elevated installer will do it instead. Otherwise, we get 
///weird behavior & errors when uninstalling mixed mode.
///</remarks>
function ShouldCreateUninstaller(): boolean;
begin
  if not IsElevated() and ShouldInstallAllUsers then
    result:= false
  else
    result:= true;
end;

///<remarks>
///Deterimine if there is a previous version of Rubberduck installed
///All uninstaller will store a registry key with the AppId, so we can
///use AppId to detect previous versions.
///</remarks>
///<param name="AppId">
///If contains a valid AppId, attempt to get uninstaller for that.
///If left blank, attempt to get uninstaller for current mode.
///</param>
function GetUninstallString(AppId: string): String;
var
  sAppId: string;
  sUnInstPath: String;
  sUnInstallString: String;
begin
  if AppId = '' then
    sAppId := GetAppId('')
  else
    sAppId := AppId;

  sUnInstPath := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\' + sAppId + '_is1';
  Log('Looking in registry: ' + sUnInstPath);
  sUnInstallString := '';
  if not RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString) then
    RegQueryStringValue(HKCU, sUnInstPath, 'UninstallString', sUnInstallString);
  Log('Result of registry query: ' + sUnInstallString);
  Result := sUnInstallString;
end;

///<remarks>
///Encapuslates the check for previous versions
///from <see cref="GetUninstallString" /> as a 
///boolean result
///</remarks>
function IsUpgrade(): boolean;
begin
  result := (GetUninstallString('') <> '');
end;

///<reamrks>
///An expanded version of IsUpgrade function, usuable only
///within [Code] section that additional provides information
///for all modes of installation.
///</remarks>
///<returns>
///An integer representing the fake ***IsInstalled enum
///</returns>
function IsUpgradeApp(): integer;
var
  PerUserExists: boolean;
  EveryoneExists: boolean;
begin
    PerUserExists := (GetUninstallString(PerUserAppId) <> '');
    EveryoneExists := (GetUninstallString(EveryoneAppId) <> '')

    if PerUserExists and EveryoneExists then
      result := BothAreInstalled
    else if PerUserExists and not EveryoneExists then
      result := PerUserIsInstalled
    else if not PerUserExists and EveryoneExists then
      result := EveryoneIsInstalled
    else
      result := NoneIsInstalled;
end;

///<remarks>
///Perform uninstall of old versions. Called in the
///<see cref="CurStepChanged" /> event function and only when
///a previous version was detected.
///</remarks>
///<param name="AppId">
///If non-blank, uninstall the specific AppId.
///Otherwise, use the selected mode to uninstall.
///</param>
///<returns>
/// Return Values:
///   1 - uninstall string is empty
///   2 - error executing the UnInstallString
///   3 - successfully executed the UnInstallString
///</returns>
function UnInstallOldVersion(AppId: string): integer;
var
  sUnInstallString: string;
  iResultCode: integer;
begin
  // default return value
  Result := 0;

  // get the uninstall string of the old app
  sUnInstallString := GetUninstallString(AppId);
  if sUnInstallString <> '' then begin
    sUnInstallString := RemoveQuotes(sUnInstallString);
    if Exec(sUnInstallString, '/SILENT /NORESTART /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES','', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, iResultCode) then
      Result := 3
    else
      Result := 2;
  end else
    Result := 1;
end;

///<remarks>
///Encapuslates the UI interaction with user to see whether to uninstall
///the previous verison of a given mode.
///<remakrs>
///<param name = "AppMode">
///Indicate which app mode to uninstall
///</param>
///<returns>
///Boolean indicating whether it was uninstalled succesffully.
///</returns>
function PromptToUninstall(AppMode: string): boolean;
var
  ErrorCode: integer;
begin
  Log('A previous version of ' + AppMode + ' was detected; prompting the user whether to uninstall');
  if IDYES = MsgBox(Format(ExpandConstant('{cm:UninstallOldVersionPrompt}'), [AppMode]), mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) then
  begin
    ErrorCode := -1;
    ErrorCode := UnInstallOldVersion(GetAppId(AppMode));
    Log(Format('The result of UninstallOldVersion for %s was %d.', [AppMode, ErrorCode]));

    if ErrorCode <> 3 then
      MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:UninstallOldVersionFail}'), mbError, MB_OK);
    result := (ErrorCode = 3);
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('Uninstall of previous version (%s) was declined by the user.');
    result := false;
  end;
end;

// Event functions called by Inno Setup
//
// NOTE: the ordering should be preserved to indicate the general sequence
//       that the Inno Setup will undergo for each event it calls. Note that
//       for certain events, it may be called more than once.

///<remarks>
///This is the first event of the installer, fires prior to the wizard
///being initialized. This is primarily used to validate that the 
///pre-requisites are met, in this case, pre-existence of .NET framework.
///</remarks>
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
   ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  // MS .NET Framework 4.5 must be installed for this application to work.
  if not IsDotNetDetected('v4.5', 0) then
  begin
    Log('User does not have the prerequisite .NET framework installed');
    MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:NETFramework40NotInstalled}'), mbCriticalError, mb_Ok);
    ShellExec('open', 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa731542', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode); 
    Result := False;
  end
  else
  begin
    Log('.Net v4.5 Framework was found on the system');
    Result := True;
  end;
end;

///<remarks>
///The second event of installer allow us to customize the wizard by 
///assessing whether we were launched in elevated context from an 
///non-elevated installer; <see cref="HasElevateSwitch" />. We then
///set up the <see cref="InstallForWhoOptionPage" /> and 
///<see cref="RegisterAddInOptionPage" /> pages. In both cases, their
///behavior differs depending on whether we are elevated, and need to be
///configured accordingly.
///</remarks>
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  HasElevateSwitch := CmdLineParamExists('/ELEVATE');
  Log(Format('HasElevateSwitch: %d', [HasElevateSwitch]));
  Log(Format('IsElevated: %d', [IsElevated()]));

  //Assume we are installing for all users if we were elevated
  ShouldInstallAllUsers := HasElevateSwitch;

  InstallForWhoOptionPage :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(
      wpWelcome,
      ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersCaption}'), 
      ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersMessage}'),
      ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersAdminDescription}'),
      True, False);

  InstallForWhoOptionPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersAdminButtonCaption}'));
  InstallForWhoOptionPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:InstallPerUserOrAllUsersUserButtonCaption}'));

  if PerUserOnly then
  begin
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.Values[1] := true;
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.CheckListBox.ItemEnabled[0] := false;
  end
    else if IsElevated() then
  begin
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.Values[0] := true;
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.CheckListBox.ItemEnabled[1] := false;
  end
    else
  begin
    InstallForWhoOptionPage.Values[1] := true;
  end;

  RegisterAddInOptionPage :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(
      wpInstalling,
      ExpandConstant('{cm:RegisterAddInCaption}'),
      ExpandConstant('{cm:RegisterAddInMessage}'),
      ExpandConstant('{cm:RegisterAddInDescription}'),
      False, False);

  RegisterAddInOptionPage.Add(ExpandConstant('{cm:RegisterAddInButtonCaption}'));
  RegisterAddInOptionPage.CheckListBox.ItemEnabled[0] := not IsElevated();
  RegisterAddInOptionPage.Values[0] := not IsElevated();
end;

///<remarks>
///This is called prior to load of the next page in question
///and is fired for each page we are about to visit.
///Normally we don't skip unless we have the elevate switch in 
///which case the elevated installer already has all the user's 
///input so it needs not ask users for those again, making it quick
///to run the elevated installer when elevated from the non-elevated
///installer. Otherwise, we verify whether we need to show the 
///<see cref="RegisterAddInOptionPage" /> which won't be if the installer
///is elevated (irrespective whether by the switch or directly by user)
///as installing addin registry keys will not work under an elevated context.
///</remarks>
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // if we've executed this instance as elevated, skip pages unless we're 
  // on the directory selection page 
  Result := not PagesSkipped and HasElevateSwitch and IsElevated() and (PageID <> wpReady);
  // if we've reached the Ready page, set our flag variable to avoid skipping further pages.
  if not Result then
  begin
    Log('PageSkipped set to true now');
    PagesSkipped := True;
  end;

  // If the installer is elevated, we cannot register the addin so we must skip the
  // custom page.
  if (PageID = RegisterAddInOptionPage.ID) and IsElevated() then
  begin
    Log('RegisterAddInOptionPage skipped because we are running elevated.');
    Result := true;
  end;

  // We don't need to show the users finished panel from the elevated installer
  // if they already have the non-elevated installer running.
  if (PageID = wpFinished) and HasElevateSwitch then
  begin
    Log('Skipping Finished page because we are running with /ELEVATE switch');
    Result := true;
  end;
end;

///<remarks>
///This is called once the user has clicked on the Next button on the wizard
///and is called for each page. Thus, we have basically a switch for different
///page, then we assess what we need to do.
///<remarks>
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  RetVal: HINSTANCE;
  UpgradeResult: integer;
begin
  // Prevent accidental extra clicks 
  Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := False;

  // We should assume true because a false value will cause the 
  // installer to stay on the same page, which may not be desirable
  // due to several branching in this prcocedure.
  Result := true;

  // We need to assess whether user might have selected some other directory
  // and whether we need to elevate in order to write to it. If elevation is
  // required, we need to confirm with the users. The actual elevation comes later.
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    if not ShouldInstallAllUsers then
    begin
      if not HaveWriteAccessToApp() then
      begin
        if IDYES = MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:ElevationRequiredForSelectedFolderWarning}'), mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) then
        begin
          Log('Setting ShouldIntallAllUsers to true because we need elevation to write to selected directory');
          ShouldInstallAllUsers := true;
        end
          else
        begin
          Log('User declined to elevate the permission so we will remain on wpSelectDir page to allow user to change the selection');
          Result := false
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end
    // If we need elevation, we will invoke the <see cref="Elevate" />
    // and verify we are able to do so. Failure should keep user on the
    // same page as the user can retry or cancel out from the non-elevated
    // installer.
    //
    // We also need to verify there are no previous versions and if there are,
    // to uninstall them. 
    else if CurPageID = wpReady then
  begin
    // Log all output of functions called by non-code sections
    Log('GetInstallPath: ' + GetInstallPath(''));
    Log('GetDllPath: ' + GetDllPath(''));
    Log('GetTlbPath32: ' + GetTlbPath32(''));
    Log('GetTlbPath64: ' + GetTlbPath64(''));
    Log(Format('InstallAllUsers: %d', [InstallAllUsers()]));
    Log(Format('CheckShouldInstallFiles: %d', [CheckShouldInstallFiles()]));
    Log(Format('GetAppId: %s', [GetAppId('')]));
    Log(Format('AppSuffix: %s', [GetAppSuffix()]));
    Log(Format('ShouldCreateUninstaller: %d', [ShouldCreateUninstaller()]));
    Log(Format('ShouldInstallAllUsers variable: %d', [ShouldInstallAllUsers]));

    if not IsElevated() and ShouldInstallAllUsers then
    begin
      Log('All-users install is required but we don''t have privilege; requesting elevation...');
      if not Elevate() then
      begin
        Log('Elevation failed or was cancelled; we cannot continue.');
        Result := False;
        MsgBox(Format(ExpandConstant('{cm:ElevationRequestFailMessage}'), [RetVal]), mbError, MB_OK);
      end;
    end;
  end
    // We should set the selected directory (WizardForm.DirEdit) with
    // appropriate default directory depending on whether the user is
    // running the installer as elevated or not. 
    else if CurPageID = InstallForWhoOptionPage.ID then
  begin
    if InstallForWhoOptionPage.Values[1] then
    begin
      ShouldInstallAllUsers := False;
      WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := ExpandConstant('{localappdata}{\}{#AppName}')
      Log('ShouldInstallAllUsers set to false because we chose You Only option');
    end
      else
    begin
      ShouldInstallAllUsers := True;
      WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := ExpandConstant('{commonappdata}{\}{#AppName}');
      Log('ShouldInstallAllUsers set to true because we chose All Users options');
    end;
    Log(Format('Selected default directory: %s', [WizardForm.DirEdit.Text]));

    //We need to check whether there's previous version to be uninstalled
    //We have to do it early enough or the installer will try to use the
    //previous version's directory, which will basically ignore the directory
    //being selected.
    UpgradeResult := IsUpgradeApp();

    if (UpgradeResult > NoneIsInstalled) then
    begin
      if IsElevated() then
      begin
        // Uninstall per user; continue regardless of result
        if (UpgradeResult = PerUserIsInstalled) or (UpgradeResult = BothAreInstalled) then
          PromptToUninstall(PerUserAppMode);

        // Uninstall all users; must succeed to continue
        if (UpgradeResult = EveryoneIsInstalled) or (UpgradeResult = BothAreInstalled) then
          result := PromptToUninstall(EveryoneAppMode);
      end
        else
      begin
        if ShouldInstallAllUsers then
        begin
          // We're asking to install for all users; so we must uninstall old version to continue
          if (UpgradeResult = EveryoneIsInstalled) or (UpgradeResult = BothAreInstalled) then
            result := PromptToUninstall(EveryoneAppMode);
        end
          else
        begin
          // Warn RE: multiple install (if both is installed, they already were warned)
          if (UpgradeResult = EveryoneIsInstalled) then
            result := (IDYES = MsgBox(ExpandConstant('{cm:WarnInstallPerUserOverEveryone}'), mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO));
        end;

        // Uninstall per user; must succeed to continue
        if result and ((UpgradeResult = PerUserIsInstalled) or (UpgradeResult = BothAreInstalled)) then
          result := PromptToUninstall(PerUserAppMode);
      end;
    end;
  end
    // if the user has allowed registration of the IDE (default) from our
    // custom page we should run RegisterAdd()
    else if CurPageID = RegisterAddInOptionPage.ID then
  begin
    if not IsElevated() and RegisterAddInOptionPage.Values[0] then
    begin
      Log('Addin registration was requested and will be performed');
      RegisterAddIn();
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Addin registration was declined because either we are elevated or the user unchecked the checkbox');
    end;
  end;

  // Re-enable the button disabled at start of procedure
  Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := True;
end;

///<remarks>
///The event function is called when wizard reaches the ready to install page.
///Because we may or may not launch an elevated installer which will show similar
///page, we need to help to make clear to the user what the installer(s) will be
///doing by adding the extra custom messages accordingly to the page.
///</remarks>
function UpdateReadyMemo(Space, NewLine, MemoUserInfoInfo, MemoDirInfo, MemoTypeInfo, MemoComponentsInfo, MemoGroupInfo, MemoTasksInfo: String): String;
var 
  output: String;
begin 
  if IsElevated() then
  begin
    output := output + ExpandConstant('{cm:WillExecuteAdminInstall}') + NewLine + NewLine;
  end
    else
  begin
    if ShouldInstallAllUsers then
    begin
      output := output + ExpandConstant('{cm:WillLaunchAdminInstall}') + NewLine + NewLine;
    end
      else
    begin
      output := output + ExpandConstant('{cm:WillInstallForCurrentUser}') + NewLine + NewLine;
    end;
  end;

  output := output + MemoDirInfo + NewLine;

  result := output;
end;

///<remarks>
///Called during uninstall, once for each step but for our purpose, we are 
///interested in only one step doing the actual uninstall.
///
///As a rule, the addin registration should be always uninstalled; there is no
///purpose in having the addin registered when the DLL gets uninstalled. Note
///this is also unconditional - it will uninstall the related registry keys.
///</remarks>
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged(CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
begin
  if CurUninstallStep = usUninstall then UnregisterAddin();
end;
```